# Images not loading from asset catalog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Tonight I opened a project I haven't opened in a while. When I run the app the images don't show and I get the following error:

```
CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name 'image'
```

I looked around but can't find a solution.

Edit:

Still no solution here. I'm not using Cocoapods in the project but checked and the gem is updated to the latest version. I don't set my images in code either, they are set directly in the Storyboard and stored in the assets catalog.

Comment: Did you update CocoaPods ? Also please paste the code you are using to display image.

Comment: I'm not using CocoaPods in the project, although I do have it installed on my computer. Would it still matter? The image is set in a Storyboard, not in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - this had nothing to do with Cocoapods. The problem was simple and a stupid mistake but one that Xcode probably should have prevented. I was testing in the simulator. When I eventually connected my iPhone and tried to run I got an error that the app was iPad only. This was despite it opening in the iPhone simulator but showing no images. Once I fixe my project settings back to Universal (no idea how it got change to iPad) the problem was solved.